# Replace ':' by 'nan'

Tags: python, numpy, csv

I am trying to open a data file and replace all the ':' by 'nan' however I am getting a AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'.

I am not allowed to use panda.

If you want to try this use this link https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/databrowser/view/sdg_07_20/default/table?lang=en
go to download select options and other formats select text and unselect compressed.

It shows that my error is inside of .read 3rd line

```
import numpy as np

datatemp = np.loadtxt("estat_sdg_07_20.tsv", delimiter =",",skiprows=1,dtype=str)
    
data =  datatemp.read().replace(':','nan')
```

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'read'.`

Comment: It looks like `loadtxt` is returning a `ndarray` object, and not a `file` object. `file` objects have a `read` method. Try replacing the second line with: `datatemp = open("estat_sdg_07_20.tsv", "r")`

Comment: That does work to replace those values by nan sucesfully. However what should I use to usecols=3,4,5 etc.. since that is not possible when you use open.

Answer (score 2):

loadtxt returns an ndarray. If you want to search and replace items in an ndarray, I suggest using the `numpy.where` function.
You could try

```
import numpy as np

datatemp = np.loadtxt("estat_sdg_07_20.tsv", delimiter =",",skiprows=1,dtype=str)

data = np.where(datatemp==':', 'nan', datatemp)
```

To explain `np.where(datatemp==':', 'nan', datatemp)`, the pseodo code is :

```
  if datatemp[i]==':':
    data[i] = `nan`
  else:
    data[i] = datatemp[i]
```